# How to secure vault_token when using envconsul

Tags: environment-variables, consul, hashicorp-vault

To manage the secret- I am planning to use [ENVCONSUL](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/developer/sm-app-integration).

As part of the envconsul setup, I have to pass VAULT_TOKEN. Now during deployment, I can pass the VAULT_TOKEN as a parameter(as suggested by hashicorp).

However- how can I keep accessing this VAULT_TOKEN securely for normal app stop/start? Because at that time, there won't be any other tool to pass that environment variable.

Comment: Are you deploying your application on some cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to securely store the token:

- If you use a password manager (bitwarden, lastpass, dashlane, etc) then you could store it there
- write it on a piece of paper and keep that safe
- don't keep the token at all - instead configure another authentication engine, and log in with that each time you need a token
- store it in an encrypted file on your hard disk. In this case you still have to securely store the encryption key or password somewhere (might be more memorable though)
- memorise the token (only joking)